# mysql login failture

Tags: authentication, linux, mysql

I have the problem that someone / something is trying to connect to my database without a user / password. Port forwarding on 3306 is not active.
My SQL error log:

```
2019-02-06T15:32:32.888533+01:00 11141 [Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-02-06T15:34:32.908937+01:00 11168 [Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-02-06T15:36:32.931560+01:00 11196 [Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-02-06T15:38:32.952347+01:00 11224 [Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-02-06T15:40:32.973641+01:00 11250 [Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-02-06T15:42:32.994320+01:00 11277 [Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How can I find out which daemon/program/file is trying to connect?
Thanks!

Comment: Ruin `netstat` or `ss` and see what local process is connecting to that port.

Comment: well, of cause it mysql? `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1189/mysqld`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is interested: It was this line in my Monit configuration:

```
if failed unixsocket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock protocol mysql for 3 times within 4 cycles then restart
```

after removing this line, the problem was gone.